# Modification of text files over ssh with Python - performance

Tags: python, performance, ssh, sed

I need to replace some lines in text files via ssh, if they contain a certain key string. I wrote the following simple Python function for that:

```
def ssh_edit_file(h, u, file_in, file_out, key, new): 
    import paramiko, string, os

    c_out = []

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.load_system_host_keys(os.environ["HOME"] + "/.ssh/known_hosts")
    ssh.connect(h,username=u)
    ftp = ssh.open_sftp()

    f_in = ftp.file(file_in, "r")
    c_in = f_in.readlines()
    for line in c_in:
        if string.find(line, key) > 0:
            c_out.append(new + '\n')
        else:
            s = line
            c_out.append(s)

   f_out = ftp.file(file_out, "w")
   f_out.writelines(c_out)

   f_in.close()
   f_out.close()
   ftp.close()
   ssh.close()
```

This is a bit slow, which is ok for most of my files. If I use it for larger files (~2k lines), speed becomes a problem. What could be done to speed this up easily?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use Python for this? It might be faster to use ssh in a bash for loop and sed to replace lines in the file.

Comment: It is part of a larger system mainly written in Python, so Python was the first idea. Doing the modification with sed could be worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) worked well for my case. In return for the helpful suggestion I like the share solution:

```
def ssh_edit_file(h, u, file_in, file_out, key, new):
    """
    SSH_EDIT_FILE - replace a line in a remote file
    """ 

    import warnings

    try:
        s = new.replace("'","\'")
        if file_in == file_out:
            ssh_exe('sed -i "s/.*' + key + '.*/' + s + '/g" ' + file_out,
                    h = h, u = u )
        else:
            ssh_exe('sed -e "s/.*' + key + '.*/' + s + '/g" ' + 
                    file_in + '>|' +  file_out,
                    h = h, u = u )
    except:
        warnings.warn('key not found')

def ssh_exe(cmd, client=None, h=None,u=None):
    """
    SSH_EXE - Run command via ssh
    """

    import paramiko, os

    if h:
        if client:
              raise RuntimeError('Please specify either client of h and u')
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.load_system_host_keys(os.environ["HOME"] + "/.ssh/known_hosts")
        client.connect(h,username=u)
    else:
        if h or u:
              raise RuntimeError('Please specify either client of h and u')

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)

    if stdout.channel.recv_exit_status():
        e = stderr.readlines()
        if not e == []:
            raise RuntimeError('Error in executing ' + cmd + '\n'.join(e))

    if h:
        client.close()
```